# How to select text from table cell that includes <br>?

Tags: xpath

I have a table that contains rows like this:

```
<tr class="premium"><td class="name"><div class="name">John Doe</div>Fancy company name<br />Elmstreet 71<br />454378 Ghostown<br />Tel.: 123 4567 891<br /></td></tr>
<tr class="basic"><td class="name"><div class="name">John Smoe</div>Fancy company name<br />Elmstreet 73<br />456378 Ghostown<br />Tel.: 123 4567 891<br /></td></tr>
```

I need the xpath to select the company name from rows with the class="premium"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the `<br>` in the title of the question have to do with your question on how to select rows with `class="premium"`? Have you had a look at xpath tutorials like http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example5.html ?

Answer (score 1):

xpath as itself returns set of strings divided by `<br>` tags. You can use string() function to take the 1st past

```
string(//tr[@class="premium"]/td[@class = "name"]/text())
```

or as kjhughes has supposed

```
//tr[@class="premium"]/td[@class = "name"]/text()[1]
```

result

```
String='Fancy company name'
```

Comment: If you add `[1]` after `text()` your XPath 1.0 dependent answer will work for XPath 2.0 too.